# use registry value in xml config file

Tags: vb.net, connection-string

My application uses an xml config file to store the following connection string to the database used in the program (the information in brackets was changed for this post).

```
<add name="VetDAR.My.MySettings.VDARSQLDBASEConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=[DATASOURCE];Initial Catalog=[INITIAL CATALOG];User ID=[UID];Password=[PASSWORD]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My program also utilizes registry keys for a great deal of information and program settings. Is it possible to utilize database connection information stored in registry keys in this connection string within the xml file? i.e. if I have a datasource key value, can I substitute [DATASOURCE] in the above connection string with the registry value?

I know how to do this in the normal vb.net forms within my application, but I don't know how (or if it is even possible) to call registry values from within an xml file. Alternatively, is it possible to override the default behavior of Visual Studio and force a dataset to use a hard-coded connection string where I can call registry values?

Answer (score 0):

What about getting the connectionString from the config file, and passing it to your database connection object.

But before you pass it to the database, you replace the values that need replacing.  So you connection string will read something like:

`Data Source=[DATASOURCE];Initial Catalog=[INITIAL CATALOG];User ID=[UID];Password=[PASSWORD]`

and then you pass to the database:

```
Dim connString As String = GetConnectionStringFromXML()
MyDatabase.ConnectionString = connString.Replace("[UID]", GetRegistryValue("UID").Replace("[INITIAL CATALOG]",GetRegistryValue("DatabaseName"))
```

...
...

Comment: Where would I do this? Do I have to do this on every form, or is the somewhere within the program that I can just put this code once- i.e. the dataset?

Comment: I would have a class dedicated to the settings that your program needs.  Each form would ask this class for the settings it needs.  That way this logic would only be in one place, and thr forms don't care how it's calculated.